# Can we do a vertical line with curve in CSS?

Tags: html, css, line, curve

Ive been searching for an answer if we can create a vertical line with curve but was not able to have found anything, maybe the community can help me with this.

I like to create a line like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
`border: px dashed color` mixed with `border-radius`

```css
div {
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

With only one dashed side:

```css
div {
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 300px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #000;
    border-left: 1px dashed #000;
    border-radius: 50px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: this is what im looking for.. thank you so much.,.